# Why doesn't this add the QObject* in QVector<QObject*>

Tags: qt, extern, qvector, qproperty

I've two ViewModels, `MainVM` and `AddVM`. In `main.cpp`, `MainVM` is declared this way:

```
MainVM *mvm;    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    mvm = new MainVM();
    ...
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mainContext", mvm);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("addContext", new AddVM());
    ...
}
```

and in `MainVM`, I've this `Q_PROPERTY`:

```
class MainVM : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    PROPERTY(QVector<Plot*>, plots)
    ...
public:
    ...
    QSqlDatabase db;
    int maxPlotId, maxSpaceId, maxTenantId, maxHeadId, maxLeaseId;
    ...
};
```

the `PROPERTY` macro does this:

```
#define PROPERTY(QType, name) \
    Q_PROPERTY(QType name READ name WRITE set##name NOTIFY name##Changed) \
    public: \
        QType name(){return m_##name;} \
        void set##name(QType value){if(m_##name != value){m_##name = value; emit name##Changed();}} \
        Q_SIGNAL void name##Changed(); \
    private: \
        QType m_##name;
```

In my `AddVM` I've another `Q_PROPERTY` newPlot and a `Q_INVOKABLE` addNewPlot:

```
class AddVM : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    PROPERTY(Plot*, newPlot)
public:
    explicit AddVM(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void addNewPlot();
};
```

on top of the `AddVM.cpp`, I've these:

```
#include "MainVM.h"
extern MainVM *mvm;
```

and `addNewPlot` function has these instructions:

```
void AddVM::addNewPlot()
{
    mvm->db.open();
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO Plots (Name, Description) VALUES(:Name, :Description)");
    query.bindValue(":Name", newPlot()->name());
    query.bindValue(":Description", newPlot()->description());
    query.exec();
    mvm->db.close();

    mvm->plots().push_back(newPlot());
    setnewPlot(new Plot());
    newPlot()->setid(++mvm->maxPlotId);
}
```

everything in this function works as expected except the `mvm->plots().push_back(newPlot());` line! This doesn't add the `newPlot` in the `QVector` of `MainVM`!

**EDIT**

Probably the best way is to redefine the `getter` in the macro like this:

```
QType& name(){return m_##name;} \
```

and with that my existing code works without any modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `mvm->plots()`, it returns a copy of the real plots vector (That's my guess because you didn't show what `plots()` does). Thus, a new plot is added to the copy not the original vector. So, I think the best way is to add a function in `MainVM` that is called 'addPlot()` for example where you can add to the plots vector internally and directly.

Comment: Yes, in the macro it returns `m_##name` and the name is `plots`. adding a function in `MainVM` will work.

Comment: I've added `QVector<Plot*>& plotsReference(){ return m_plots;}` function in MainVM and instead of `plots()->push_back` in `addNewPlot()` now I've `plotsReference()->push_back`.  Thanks.